# running java rmi server

Tags: java, server, rmi

I am creating a project with RMI technology and it's running as I want but now I want to upload my RMI class to the server, how and what should I do that ?

I tried to do this:

```
public static void main (String [] arg) {
    try {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(30);
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1",30);
        ImbCal  c = new ImbCal();

        reg.rebind("MSA", c);
        reg.rebind("Work", c);

        System.out.println("Server is ready ....");

        System.in.read();


    }catch(Exception ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
      System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I know that should:

1. change localhost address.
2. create deployment jar for server like ear or war.

I have already created an interface and a client class and tested my project locally and it works perfectly.

Comment: What does ''upload my RMI class to the server' mean?

Comment: I mean by " upload my RMI class to the server " that i want to run it via server , not locally .
Also , i want to know how to create deployment jar .
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot until i solved it , I just need to create registry  in server class while in client class i should get registry by the address of server class

Server class :

```
try {
    /*here create the registry*/
    Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(30);
    ImbCal  c = new ImbCal();
    reg.rebind("MSA", c);
    reg.rebind("Work", c);
    System.out.println("Server is ready ....");
    System.in.read();
}catch(Exception ex){
  ex.printStackTrace();
  System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Client Class :

```
        try {               
            Registry myReg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.1.5",30);      
            System.out.println("running...");
            CalInterface c= (CalInterface)myReg.lookup("MSA");      
             WorkInterface w= (WorkInterface)myReg.lookup("Work");  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with 'upload[ing] my RMI class to the server'?